# Determining if a function has a derivative of 0 using data from a table

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is a question I cannot seem to figure out (number 2). 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qzWK.png]

I have tried using the Mean Value theorem, but I cant' find a way to justify there being or not being a derivative of 0 somewhere. Because the function is strictly increasing, there are no common points, so Rolle's theorem is out of the picture. Any help would be much appreciated. I think this problem is probably easy and that I'm just having a brain-fart, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: The statement told you $R$ is increasing...

Comment: The function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto x^3$ is also increasing. Nevertheless $f'(0)=0$.